# Open Gmail App on an specific email

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail

There is any way to open an specific email using the email url or id?

If you look gmail, when you open an email, in your browser, it's show you an url like this:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/14b2757234f88774

So, I'm loking for a way to open that specific mail on gmail android app.

Maybe using Intent or something else

Any idea?

Thanks and sorry for my poor English

Comment: `a specific email` how would you know which email you want to open?

Comment: In my application i'm receiving a list of email from a web services. I show the list and the user select which one like to open

Comment: how does your app knows about the specific emails from the user's mailbox?

Comment: in particular, are you able to receive the `14b2757234f88774` id?

Comment: I doesn't know yet. I'm doing a Proof of Concept. I have to show some ideas to my client. I suppose that I can use the email's url

Comment: open an email from the notification, and look at the logcat when you do that. There are a few details on the content of the intent used.